# where condition in select query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have to check both the user name and the email if any of the two already exist,

When I add `OR` in `where` condition It is always going in IF condition.

Code:

```
$fetch_user=mysql_query("SELECT userid FROM users WHERE username ='".$username."' OR email='".$email."'") or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($fetch_user))
{ 
    echo '<font color="red">The nickname <strong>'.$username.''.$email.'</strong>'.' is already in use.</font>';
} 
else 
{
    $query = mysql_query("insert into users values ('','$username','$email','$password','','$roll')") or die(mysql_error());
    if($query)
    {
        echo 'Successfully Inserted';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Insertion Faild';
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what is not working ? any error you got ?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if(mysql_num_rows($fetch_user) > 0)`

Comment: meaning the supplied username/email one of them is in the table and its returning some value.

Comment: u need `and` not `OR` or will take any of the two conditon and show whereas and will check if both are true

Comment: @juergend Not necessary to add `> 0` in this instance

Comment: @annampriyatam there is no difference between your query and OP's query putting where inside braces does not help anything unless there is a combination of `OR` `AND` in the condition.

Comment: oh ok.. thnx for the confirmation.. I used to think it works like that.. Thank You.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any thing wrong in the code. However i can only see the logic is incorrect. If username or email already exists, you are showing a message that `nickname username and email already in use`. It may be possible that only username is already in use but not the email and vice versa. So you need to show proper message to the user which one is taken and which one not.

```
<?php 
$userNameTaken = false;
$emailTaken = false;

//check if username exists
$checkUsername = mysql_query("SELECT userid FROM users WHERE username ='".$username."'") or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($checkUsername))
{ 
    $userNameTaken = true;
}

//check if email exists
$checkEmail = mysql_query("SELECT userid FROM users WHERE email ='".$email."'") or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($checkEmail))
{ 
    $emailTaken = true;
}

if($userNameTaken || $emailTaken) //if any of username or email taken
{
    if($userNameTaken && $emailTaken) //username and email both taken
    {
        echo '<font color="red">The username <strong>'.$username.'</strong> and email <strong>'.$email.'</strong> already in use.</font>';
    }
    else if($userNameTaken && !$emailTaken) //only username taken
    {
        echo '<font color="red">The username <strong>'.$username.'</strong> is already in use.</font>';
    }
    else if(!$userNameTaken && $emailTaken) //only email taken 
    {
        echo '<font color="red">The email <strong>'.$email.'</strong> is already in use.</font>';
    }
} 
else 
{
    $query = mysql_query("insert into users values ('','$username','$email','$password','','$roll')") or die(mysql_error());
    if($query)
    {
        echo 'Successfully Inserted';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Insertion Faild';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only change condition

```
    $fetch_user=mysql_query("SELECT userid FROM users WHERE username ='".$username."' OR email='".$email."'") or die(mysql_error());
    $num = mysql_num_rows($fetch_user);
    if($num > 1)
    { 
        echo '<font color="red">The nickname <strong>'.$username.''.$email.'</strong>'.' is already in use.</font>';
    } 
    else 
    {
        $query = mysql_query("insert into users values ('','$username','$email','$password','','$roll')") or die(mysql_error());
        if($query)
        {
            echo 'Successfully Inserted';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Insertion Faild';
        }
    }
```

Comment: `if($num > 1)` is same as `if(mysql_num_rows($fetch_user))`

Comment: if(mysql_num_rows($fetch_user)) missing > 1 look at that if condition @KhawerZeshan

Comment: total num of user $num = mysql_num_rows($fetch_user); greater then 1 @KhawerZeshan your mistack not my mistack

Comment: `if(mysql_num_rows($fetch_user))` has `0` that will be false, otherwise it will be considered as true. So no need for `>` check

Answer (score 0):

You are not validating the result from teh sql query .
the following code will work

```css
$fetch_user=mysql_query("SELECT userid FROM users WHERE username ='".$username."' OR email='".$email."'") or die(mysql_error());
if( !$fetch_user)
{
 if(mysql_num_rows($fetch_user) > 0 )
 { 
  echo '<font color="red">The nickname <strong>'.$username.''.$email.'</strong>'.' is already in use.</font>';
 } 

else 
{
    $query = mysql_query("insert into users values ('','$username','$email','$password','','$roll')") or die(mysql_error());
    if($query)
    {
        echo 'Successfully Inserted';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Insertion Faild';
    }
}
}
else
[
echo 'query failed';
}
```

Also look the following documentation links so you understand the functionalities better 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: 1) You missed the `$` sign. `if( !fetch_user)` should be `if( !$fetch_user)` 2) `if( !$fetch_user)` should be `if($fetch_user)` 3) `if($fetch_user)` will only check if the query has no error and successfully executed. So technically it will not make any difference

Comment: the above code works perfectly fine for me  ...  u could also try mysql_fetch_assoc  function  to read the row values ...